# SSHNet and MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ssh

I am trying to integrate SSHNet to .Net desktop application. I was able to establish the SSH connection, however when i try to connect MySql (remote server) i get stream read error. I used the same configuration for SQL that I use in Toad and the same configuration for the SSH that I use in BitVise.

My guess is there is no handshake establish.  I notice that in Bitvise Client there is a key exchange between the server and the client, I am not sure how to implement such exchange and if this is really the issue. I used different profile (username/password/servers) to test.

If someone can help me, I will be glad

here is the code i use:

```
Public Structure utProfileDef
    Dim IP As String
    Dim sshUSR As String
    Dim sshPWD As String
    Dim DBUsr As String
    Dim DBPwd As String
    Dim DBName As String
    Dim DBPort As Integer
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim sshPort As Integer
End Structure

Public Class Form1
    Dim WithEvents oSSHClient As SshClient

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim utProfile(1) As utProfileDef

        With utProfile(0)
            .IP = "myserver1"
            .sshPort = 22
            .sshUSR = "myuser"
            .sshPWD = "mypassword"
            .DBName = "mydatabase"
            .DBUsr = "dbuser"
            .DBPwd = "dbpassword"
            .DBPort = 3308
            .SQL = "SELECT * FROM Categorie"
        End With

        With utProfile(1)
            .IP = "myserver2"
            .sshPort = 22000
            .sshUSR = "myuser1"
            .sshPWD = "mypassword1"
            .DBName = "mydatabase1"
            .DBUsr = "dbuser1"
            .DBPwd = "dbpassword1"
            .DBPort = 22001
            .SQL = "SELECT * FROM Scan"
        End With

        Call sshClientConnect(utProfile(0))
    End Sub

    Protected Sub DBConnect(utCurrentProfile As utProfileDef)
        Dim oCnn As New MySqlConnection
        Dim oCMD As MySqlCommand
        Dim oDBR As MySqlDataReader

        oCnn.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1; port=" & utCurrentProfile.DBPort & _
                                "; user id=" & utCurrentProfile.DBUsr & _
                                "; password=" & utCurrentProfile.DBPwd & _
                                "; database=" & utCurrentProfile.DBName & ";Pooling=true;"

        Try
            oCnn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End
        End Try

        oCMD = New MySqlCommand(utCurrentProfile.SQL, oCnn)
        oDBR = oCMD.ExecuteReader

        While oDBR.Read
            MsgBox(oDBR.Item(0))
        End While

        oDBR.Close()
        oCnn.Close()
    End Sub


    Protected Sub sshClientConnect(utCurrentProfile As utProfileDef)
        Dim oPort As Renci.SshNet.ForwardedPortLocal


        oSSHClient = New SshClient(utCurrentProfile.IP, utCurrentProfile.sshPort, utCurrentProfile.sshUSR, utCurrentProfile.sshPWD)
        oSSHClient.Connect()
        oPort = New Renci.SshNet.ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", utCurrentProfile.DBPort, "127.0.0.1", utCurrentProfile.DBPort)
        oSSHClient.AddForwardedPort(oPort)
        oPort.Start()

        MsgBox(IIf(oSSHClient.IsConnected, "SSH Connected to " & utCurrentProfile.IP, "SSH not connected"))


        Call DBConnect(utCurrentProfile)

        oPort.Stop()
        oPort.Dispose()
        oSSHClient.Disconnect()
    End Sub

    Private Sub oSSHClient_HostKeyReceived(sender As Object, e As Common.HostKeyEventArgs) Handles oSSHClient.HostKeyReceived
        e.CanTrust = True
    End Sub
```

Thanks